# about GDB and CRC mismatch

Tags: c++, gcc, gdb

I want to use `gdb` to debug the code. When I write the command:

```
gdb gdns_processor
```

It will output the warning message from `gdb`:

```
<http://www.gnu.org/software/gdb/bugs/>...
Reading symbols from /usr/local/gdnscenter/bin/gdns_processor...
warning: the debug information found in "/usr/lib/debug//usr/local/gdnscenter/bin/gdns_processor.debug" does not match "/usr/local/gdnscenter/bin/gdns_processor" (CRC mismatch).
warning: the debug information found in "/usr/lib/debug/usr/local/gdnscenter/bin/gdns_processor.debug" does not match "/usr/local/gdnscenter/bin/gdns_processor" (CRC mismatch).

(no debugging symbols found)...done.
```

I don't understand CRC mismatch. Why `gdb` can't find symbols?

PS: My `gcc` options have set `-g` flag.

```
CPPFLAGS="-D_LIBC_REENTRANT $CPPFLAGS -g"
```

Comment: Make sure that the package has same version with debuginfo package. I just upgrade my package. Say, glibc-debuginfo-common-2.28-39.fc29.x86_64, glibc-debuginfo-2.28-39.fc29.x86_64 , glibc-2.28-33.fc29.x86_64, glibc-common-2.28-33.fc29.x86_64. Just `sudo dnf upgrade glibc`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> I don't understand CRC mismatch

To understand the message, you need to read about GDBs use of "separate debug files", e.g. [here](http://sourceware.org/gdb/onlinedocs/gdb/Separate-Debug-Files.html).

> my Gcc options have set -g. `CPPFLAGS="-D_LIBC_REENTRANT $CPPFLAGS -g"`

It is likely you are not telling us the whole story. Your build procedure probably produces the `gdns_processor` binary, and the `gdns_processor.debug` "separate debug file" for it.

You then copy the `gdns_processor` to `/usr/local/gdnsceter/bin/`, but (apparently) neglect to copy `gdns_processor.debug` into `/usr/lib/debug/usr/local/gdnscenter/bin/`.

Comment: Thank you. the gdns_processor binary is in /usr/local/gdnsceter/bin/. And  the gdns_processor.debug is in /usr/lib/debug//usr/local/gdnscenter/bin/.  I will read this Debugging Information in Separate Files

Comment: " In addition, the debug link specifies a 32-bit Cyclic Redundancy Check (CRC) checksum for the debug file, which gdb uses to validate that the executable and the debug file came from the same build.  "       But my system is x86_64. so the CRC checksum is wrong ?

Comment: I try this:(gdb) symbol-file /usr/lib/debug/usr/local/gdnscenter/bin/gdns_processor.debug
Reading symbols from /usr/lib/debug/usr/local/gdnscenter/bin/gdns_processor.debug...done.

Comment: Sorry, I make a mistake. CRC  is wrong,because I build the project in different times.like:gdnscenter-1.3.0-7.x86_64.rpm and gdnscenter-debuginfo-1.3.0-6.x86_64.rpm

Answer (score 0):

maybe the program you debugging mismatch the source code, considering recompile the program. PS: if you want more detail of the debug information, you can use -ggdb option.