# CRC mismatch warning running helloworld.c from gdb on ubuntu 20.04.3

Tags: c, linux, ubuntu, gcc, gdb

I have the most trivial program

```
$ cat helloworld.c
#include <stdio.h>
int main(void){
  printf("Hello World!\n");
  return 0;
}

$ gcc -g helloworld.c -o helloworld
```

Which I'm wanting to run under gdb

```
$ gdb -tui ./helloworld
```

When I run, from within gdb,

```
warning: the debug information found in "/lib64/ld-2.31.so" does not match "/lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2" (CRC mismatch).
```

I think my system is up to date. I've already run

```
$ sudo apt-get update
$ sudo apt-get upgrade
```

I've attempted to reinstall any libc6* packages

```
$ apt list --installed | grep 'libc6'

WARNING: apt does not have a stable CLI interface. Use with caution in scripts.  
libc6-amd64/focal-updates,now 2.31-0ubuntu9.2 i386 [installed,automatic]  
libc6-dbg/focal-updates,now 2.31-0ubuntu9.2 amd64 [installed,automatic]  
libc6-dev-amd64/focal-updates,now 2.31-0ubuntu9.2 i386 [installed,automatic]  
libc6-dev/focal-updates,now 2.31-0ubuntu9.2 amd64 [installed,automatic]  
libc6-dev/focal-updates,now 2.31-0ubuntu9.2 i386 [installed,automatic]  
libc6/focal-updates,now 2.31-0ubuntu9.2 amd64 [installed,automatic]  
libc6/focal-updates,now 2.31-0ubuntu9.2 i386 [installed,automatic]
```

followed by, for each of those 7 packages, the equivalent of

```
$ sudo apt-get --reinstall install 'libc6-amd64'
```

but the warning is the same as previously.

Regarding ld-2.31.so, mentioned by @employedrussian in the comments

```
$ ls -lsh /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2
0 lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 32 Dec 16  2020 /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 -> /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/ld-2.31.so
$ ls -lsh /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/ld-2.31.so 
188K -rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 187K Dec 16  2020 /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/ld-2.31.so

$ ls -lsh /lib64/ld-2.31.so 
180K -rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 178K Dec 16  2020 /lib64/ld-2.31.so

$ dpkg -S /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2
libc6:amd64: /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2

$ dpkg -S /lib64/ld-2.31.so
libc6-amd64:i386: /lib64/ld-2.31.so
```

I've uninstalled libc6-dev-amd64 as identified by @employedrussian below

```
$ sudo apt-get purge libc6-dev-amd64
```

```
$ apt list --installed | grep libc6

WARNING: apt does not have a stable CLI interface. Use with caution in scripts.

libc6-amd64/focal-updates,now 2.31-0ubuntu9.2 i386 [installed,auto-removable]
libc6-dbg/focal-updates,now 2.31-0ubuntu9.2 amd64 [installed,automatic]
libc6-dev/focal-updates,now 2.31-0ubuntu9.2 amd64 [installed,automatic]
libc6-dev/focal-updates,now 2.31-0ubuntu9.2 i386 [installed,auto-removable]
libc6/focal-updates,now 2.31-0ubuntu9.2 amd64 [installed,automatic]
libc6/focal-updates,now 2.31-0ubuntu9.2 i386 [installed,automatic]
```

But the exact same error reported in gdb remains

/lib64/ld-2.31.so is still present

```
$ cd /lib64
$ ls -l ld-2.31.so
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 182168 Dec 16  2020 ld-2.31.so
```

libc6-amd64:i386 is still installed

```
$ dpkg -l | grep libc6-amd64
ii  libc6-amd64:i386  2.31-0ubuntu9.2  i386  GNU C Library: 64bit Shared libraries for AMD64

$ apt list --installed | grep libc6-amd64
WARNING: apt does not have a stable CLI interface. Use with caution in scripts.
libc6-amd64/focal-updates,now 2.31-0ubuntu9.2 i386 [installed,auto-removable]
```

Attempting to remove the package fails

```
$ sudo dpkg --remove libc6-amd64:i386
[sudo] password for rgh: 
dpkg: dependency problems prevent removal of libc6-amd64:i386:
 lib64tinfo6:i386 depends on libc6-amd64 (>= 2.16).
 lib64ncursesw6:i386 depends on libc6-amd64 (>= 2.14).
 lib64ncurses6:i386 depends on libc6-amd64 (>= 2.14).

dpkg: error processing package libc6-amd64:i386 (--remove):
 dependency problems - not removing
Errors were encountered while processing:
 libc6-amd64:i386
```

I do remember installing some ncurses packages a while back.

```
$ lsb_release -a
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 20.04.3 LTS
Release:    20.04
Codename:   focal
```

Comment: There may be an answer to this [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12927797/645128) where the answerer links [this](http://sourceware.org/gdb/onlinedocs/gdb/Separate-Debug-Files.html)

Comment: You probably have some packages of mismatched versions installed (libc6* ? Try reinstalling these).

Comment: @EugeneSh. Assuming I've done as you suggest, that didn't work. I've updated the question accordingly.

Comment: What does `ls -l /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 /lib64/ld-2.31.so` show? Likewise for `dpkg -S /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 /lib64/ld-2.31.so` ? Normal Debian system should _not have_ `/lib64/ld-2.31.so` at all AFAIU.

Comment: Thanks @employedrussian I've updated the question to show the output from those commands.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This appears to be the root cause:

> `$ dpkg -S /lib64/ld-2.31.so`
> `libc6-amd64:i386: /lib64/ld-2.31.so`

According to [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/questions/660759/confused-about-packages-libc6-amd64-and-libc6amd64), `libc6-amd64:i386` is a 64bit cross-compile tool-chain prepared for Ubuntu 32bit. Since you are on a 64-bit system, this package is useless.

Uninstalling it will likely fix your warning.

**Update:**

> Trying to understand this

The format in which `apt list` and `dpkg -l` show package names is different. On my system:

```
dpkg-query -l libc6* | grep '^ii'

ii  libc6:amd64           2.32-4       amd64        GNU C Library: Shared libraries
ii  libc6:i386            2.32-4       i386         GNU C Library: Shared libraries
ii  libc6-dbg:amd64       2.32-4       amd64        GNU C Library: detached debugging symbols
ii  libc6-dev:amd64       2.32-4       amd64        GNU C Library: Development Libraries and Header Files
ii  libc6-dev-i386        2.32-4       amd64        GNU C Library: 32-bit development libraries for AMD64
ii  libc6-dev-x32         2.32-4       amd64        GNU C Library: X32 ABI Development Libraries for AMD64
ii  libc6-i386            2.32-4       amd64        GNU C Library: 32-bit shared libraries for AMD64
ii  libc6-x32             2.32-4       amd64        GNU C Library: X32 ABI Shared libraries for AMD64
```

versus:

```
apt list --installed libc6*

libc6-dbg/...,now 2.32-4 amd64 [installed,automatic]
libc6-dev-i386/...,now 2.32-4 amd64 [installed,automatic]
libc6-dev-x32/...,now 2.32-4 amd64 [installed,automatic]
libc6-dev/...,now 2.32-4 amd64 [installed,automatic]
libc6-i386/...,now 2.32-4 amd64 [installed,automatic]
libc6-x32/...,now 2.32-4 amd64 [installed,automatic]
libc6/...,now 2.32-4 amd64 [installed]
libc6/...,now 2.32-4 i386 [installed,automatic]
```

I believe the package you want to remove is this one:

```
libc6-dev-amd64/focal-updates,now 2.31-0ubuntu9.2 i386 [installed,automatic]
```

Comment: Trying to understand this. $ apt list --installed | grep 'libc6' lists the packages I have installed, as in my question. 'libc6-amd64:i386:' is not amongst them. Yet $ dpkg -S /lib64/ld-2.31.so says /lib64/ld-2.31.so is in that package. How can I uninstall a package that isn't installed?

Comment: @rgh I've updated the answer.

Comment: I've removed libc6-dev-amd64 via $ sudo apt-get purge libc6-dev-amd64 but the error remains.

Comment: @rgh Is the problem file -- `/lib64/ld-2.31.so` still present? Does `dpkg -l` show that `libc6-amd64:i386` is still installed? What happens if you `sudo dpkg --remove libc6-amd64:i386` ?

Comment: I've updated the question. Yes, /lib64/ld-2.31.so is still present. Package libc6-amd64:i386 is still installed. Trying to remove the package fails. Is the root cause of this problem that I installed a 32 bit version of ncurses?

Comment: @rgh Yes, you also need to remove the other useless packages which depend on libc6-amd64:i386